# Is there a standard way in JS to download a large file from the backend using a passcode/password?

Tags: javascript, rest, file, browser, download

I am creating an application where users can download a huge file/s (around 8GB, depending on the user). The file must be password protected, so a GET request with a param isn't ideal.

Using .blob() on the response leads to RAM issues if the file is too big.

I also checked https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js but I would prefer something more "official" if possible.

How do websites like TransferXL or WeTransfer achieve this ?

Comment: Is this downloaded file then supposed to be saved to disk? Not to be displayed in the browser, correct? Is it the file or the connection that should be password protected?

Comment: @ControlAltDel the file is supposed to be saved on the disk, like a normal browser download. The connection should be "authenticated", so if I don't know the password, the backend shouldn't send me anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication is traditionally done on the server side with an App Server (like PHP), where the user goes to a page and enters their user name and password. If the password matches, the App Server creates a session cookie (if one hasn't been previously created) and adds the user id as "signed in".

This is what I recommend to you, as JavaScript is too insecure.